# Choosing test method of bash command output with bats

Tags: design, unit-testing, logging, bash

### Context

While writing a bash script I would like to test every command I write. To do so I create a separate function per command that executes the function. In addition I want to log the output of each command to be able to inspect the results later on. My doubt is about whether I should test the output of the command directly or to test it by reading it from the log file.

### Code

So I have a file named `apt_update.sh` that runs `sudo apt update`, and it contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
install_git() {
    LOG_PATH=$1
    update=$(sudo apt update)
    echo $update > $LOG_PATH
}
install_git "$@"
```

And a `bats` test file that contains:

```
#!./test/libs/bats/bin/bats

load 'libs/bats-support/load'
load 'libs/bats-assert/load'

source src/hardcoded_variables.txt

mkdir -p src/logs

@test "running the file in /src/git_install.sh." {
    chmod +x src/install_git.sh
    LOG_PATH=$LOG_LOCATION"/install_git.txt"
    run ./src/install_git.sh $LOG_PATH
    LOG_ENDING=$(tail -c 67 $LOG_PATH)
    EXPECTED_OUTPUT="packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them."
    
    assert_equal "$LOG_ENDING" "$EXPECTED_OUTPUT"
}
```

The output of the test is:

```
✓ running the file in /src/git_install.sh.

1 test, 0 failures
```

And the output of the `echo $update > $LOG_PATH` is: `WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.`

### Question

Would it be better to test the output of the function directly or would it be better to test the output that is put into the log file?

### Doubts

I am not yet quite sure how to export the output of the command in the function without modifying the string that is returned. This means writing the output to file interferes with the expected test value.

Comment: If I change the assert to: `assert_output "$EXPECTED_OUTPUT"` the test fails based on the output that would normally be printed in the CLI by the last line/command in the function. It fails with `WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.`. From what I understood the `install_git()` function returns the terminal output of the last echo/command in the function to the test. That is what I mean with *the output of the function*. What should I call that?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/990838/371118 explains how to avoid this warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a shell script in the role of a "Subject Under Test" produces deterministic output on multiple channels, like

- stdout, and/or
- stderr, and/or
- a log file
- a return code

then for creating an automated test, it can make sense to define the expected output for all of these channels, and compare it with the actual output individually.

Ideally, one does not have to change anything in the script itself for producing testable output. However, if a script is "too quiet" in what it does internally, it may be actually hard to find out if it operated successfully, so sometimes it may be necessary to add further logging specifially for the purpose of testing.

However, there can be also the opposite situation: if a log file is used to monitor a lot of internal activity, writing tests against its expected content may become easily brittle and break with the slightest refactoring in the script, or by minor changes to the environment which actually don't affect the functionality. This can be overcome by introducing different logging levels, for example a "verbose" level for monitoring, and a "standard level" suitable for tests.

So, as often in software engineering, it is a trade-off situation, where you can only decide on a by-case basis what works best.

---

As a side note, lots of devs would not call something which involves file or stream I/O a **unit** test - the term **regression test** fits IMHO better.

Comment: As obvious as it seems in retrospect I did not think of the possibility to test all output streams. I greatly appreciate how clearly you explained some ideal scenarios and different trade-offs that I did not yet consider!